# CA-IDMS LRF Erase

Tags: mainframe, erase

I have an OBTAIN FIRST followed by a loop. In the loop I have an ERASE statement and an OBTAIN NEXT.

```
PERFORM LEES-LC4DP-LC4DP-DAT-GE-E              
PERFORM UNTIL LR-STATUS NOT = 'LC4DP-AANW' OR  
              LC4DP-KALDAG > H-AL0726-IN-DATTOT
  IF LC4DP-KALDAG >= H-AL0726-IN-DATVAN AND    
     LC4DP-KALDAG <= H-AL0726-IN-DATTOT AND    
     LC4DP-KUMDAG-KOD = H-AL0726-IN-KUMDAG-KOD 
  THEN                                         
    PERFORM ERASE-LC4DP                        
  END-IF                                       
  PERFORM LEES-LC4DP-LC4DP-DAT-GE-V
```

At a certain moment I ERASE the **last record in the SET**. After that, my OBTAIN NEXT statement returns a 'LR-NOT-FOUND' while I was expecting a 0326.

**Why does it return LR-NOT-FOUND?**

LRF:

```
SELECT  FOR KEYWORD LC4DP-DAT-GE                         
        OBTAIN FIRST LC4JRDR-02                             
            WHERE CALCKEY EQ LC4JR02-KEYJR OF LR            
            ON 0000 NEXT                                    
            ON 0326 RETURN LC4JR-NIET-AANW                  
        COMPUTE LC4DP-KUMDAG-KOD OF LR = '.'                
            ON 0000 NEXT                                    
        OBTAIN FIRST LC4DPDR-01 WITHIN LC4JR02-LC4DP01      
            WHERE SORTKEY EQ LC4DP-KEYDP OF LR              
            ON 0000 RETURN LC4DP-AANW                       
            ON 0326 NEXT                                    
        OBTAIN EACH PRIOR LC4DPDR-01 WITHIN LC4JR02-LC4DP01 
            WHERE LC4DP-KALDAG GE LC4DP-KALDAG OF LR        
            ON 0000 RETURN LC4DP-AANW                       
            ON 0307 RETURN LC4DP-NIET-AANW
```

OBTAIN FIRST

```
OBTAIN FIRST LC4JR03-LR WHERE LC4DP-DAT-GE             
EVALUATE LR-STATUS                                     
WHEN 'LC4DP-AANW'                                      
  ACCEPT H-DBKEY-LC4DP FROM LC4DPDR-01 CURRENCY        
  PERFORM CONVERSIE-DB-LC4DP                           
WHEN 'LC4DP-NIET-AANW'                                 
WHEN 'LC4JR-NIET-AANW'                                 
  CONTINUE                                             
WHEN OTHER                                             
  DISPLAY 'LR-STATUS=' LR-STATUS                       
  MOVE '22'                 TO AL0726W1-OUT-FOUT-KOD   
  GOBACK                                               
END-EVALUATE
```

OBTAIN NEXT

```
OBTAIN NEXT  LC4JR03-LR WHERE LC4DP-DAT-GE           
EVALUATE LR-STATUS                                   
WHEN 'LC4DP-AANW'                                    
  ACCEPT H-DBKEY-LC4DP FROM LC4DPDR-01 CURRENCY      
  PERFORM CONVERSIE-DB-LC4DP                         
WHEN 'LC4DP-NIET-AANW'                               
WHEN 'LC4JR-NIET-AANW'                               
  CONTINUE                                           
WHEN OTHER                                           
  DISPLAY 'LR-STATUS=' LR-STATUS                                        
  MOVE '23'                 TO AL0726W1-OUT-FOUT-KOD 
  GOBACK                                             
END-EVALUATE
```